# Start VMWare VM upon remote connection

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am hosting a VM of winXP from my brother, who has a slower computer and wants to use my power xD. The issue is I hate having to have my VM running the entire time when he just uses it about 1 hour about three times a week. Is there a way in VMware to start the VMware when he tries to connect to it?
He has a Mac and I have windows 7
Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare server does that automatically. It is free so you might as well upgrade...

I use it all the time - I setup desktop shortcuts to viewer with VM parameters and VM is started if not already running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware to any such feature. "Wake up on LAN" comes in mind, but AFAIK, VMWare doesn't support that.

What VMWare does support is a web-based (IIS) management console, that allows starting up and shutting down a VM. So your brother  can log-in remotely via a browser to the administration page, turn the VM on, and log into it.